# How can I add headers to an XCFramework package?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, xcframework, swift-package

I'm trying to wrap an XCFramework as a swift package.  Following the documentation, I have created a package with the following directory structure:

```
/MyXCFPackage
    /Package.swift
    /MyXCFPackage.xcframework
    /include <- some additional headers here
```

And my `Package.swift` looks like so:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.6
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyXCFPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyXCFPackage",
            targets: ["MyXCFPackage"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "MyXCFPackage",
            path: "./MyXCFPackage.xcframework"
        )
    ]
)
```

The thing is, this framework was not structured originally for Swift Package Manager, and the XCFramework does not contain the headers, just the `.a` files for the library.  As a result, when I include this package in a client project, the headers are not available.

In the instructions for the framework, it says that the `/include` directory should be added to the Xcode build settings under `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` .

How can I get these headers into the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` through Swift Package Manager?

Answer (score 1):

The headers need to be bundled **within** the XCFramework. You can specify the headers when you create it. See the usage information outputted by the `xcodebuild -create-xcframework -help` command:

```bash
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library <path> [-headers <path>] [-library <path> [-headers <path>]...] -output <path>
```

So, to create an XCFramework from a static library and include headers, the command is:

```bash
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-library MyXCFPackage \
-headers ./include \
-output MyXCFPackage.xcframework
```

See the [Generate the XCFramework bundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle#Generate-the-XCFramework-bundle) Apple Developer guide for further information.